# Chrome (Brave) DevTools Sources Panel missing JS colors and tooltips

Tags: google-chrome, colors, javascript, google-chrome-devtools, brave

Suddenly my Brave app's Dev Tools Sources Panel is missing colors and tooltips for JavaScript files.

Here's what I see in Brave:

[image: Unexpected Screenshot]

Here's that same file JS file on the same breakpoint in Chrome, with JS colors a tooltip by hover of a variable:

[image: Expected Screenshot]

This appears to be occurring for any JS file on any website. I've tried quitting and relaunching Brave app. I've poked through the DevTools controls and prefs and online docs. What could be causing this, how might I fix it?

- MacOS Catalina 10.15.1 (19B88)
- Brave Version 1.1.20 Chromium: 79.0.3945.74 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Chrome Version 79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Here is the temporary solution for that ,you can use google canary:https://www.google.com/intl/ru/chrome/canary/    UPDATE
canary kinda works, but now it skips breakpoints at all, so use debugger; to trigger debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Six months later, as of Brave Version 1.10.95 (Chromium: 83.0.4103.106), this issue seems to have resolved itself.